# In numpy, how to create an array of the indices of the elements in a source array as they are found in a destination array?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm sure this question has been answered somewhere, but I just can't find the words to look for it.

I have these two arrays:

```
import numpy as np

src = np.array([[8, 1],
                [2, 4]]) 

dst = np.array([[1, 4],
                [8, 2]])
```

I would like to get this array:

```
indices = (np.array([[1, 0],
                     [1, 0]]),
           np.array([[0, 0],
                     [1, 1]]))
```

Such that `dst[indices]` gets me `src`.

Any ideas? Moreover, what is the kind of operation that I'm looking for called? So that I can search more about it by myself in the future.

Comment: This is similar to `np.indices(src.shape)`

Comment: I don't know the answer, but maybe something to think about: what would you want the result to be if an element is repeated? E.g. `src = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]])` and `dst = np.array([[3, 1], [2, 2]])`, then what would `indices` be?

Comment: @Safron Yes! I've thought about that. I guess I would like it to raise an exception. It's presumed that each array cell is unique and that they are the same between src and dst. Like puzzle pieces that are just shuffled around.

Comment: Argsort both arrays, then inverse argsort one. It's the only extra step with 2D is raveling the index afterwards.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That looks good, I'm gonna look more into it.

Comment: Keep shuffling the array until it matches.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That would work. I just don't have factorial time in front of me, I'm in a bit of a hurry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I believe is the "direct" way:

```
# find order of src and dst
so = src.ravel().argsort()
do = dst.ravel().argsort()
# allocate combined map
tot = np.empty_like(src)

# next line is all you need to remember
tot.ravel()[so] = do

# go back to 2D indexing
indices = np.unravel_index(tot,dst.shape)

# check
dst[indices]
# array([[8, 1],
#        [2, 4]])

indices
# (array([[1, 0],
#         [1, 0]]), array([[0, 0],
#         [1, 1]]))
```

Comment: This also does seem somewhat simpler than mine. Congrats! :)

Comment: This seems very clear and logical. Thank you very much! I'm trying it and will report back afterwards.

Comment: Okay, tested, makes perfect sense, this is just perfect ! Moreover, what I find really elegant is that, by just changing the line `tot.ravel()[so] = do` to `tot.ravel()[do] = so`, you get sort of the inverse transformation (so that instead of `dst[indices] = src` you have `src[indices] = dst`). I hadn't asked for that but it's cool. So thank you again for the help, Paul!

Answer (score 3):

Tricky.

Unfortunately, `numpy` doesn't offer a way of answering the question "Which indices should I use to transform one array into the other?"

It does, however, offer us a way to answer the question "Which indices should I use to transform an array into its sorted version?" in the form of [`argsort()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), and we can exploit that. (inspired by @Mad_Physicist comment)

### TL;DR

```
flat_row_indices, flat_column_indices = np.unravel_index(np.ravel(dst).argsort()[np.ravel(src).argsort().argsort()], src.shape)
indices = (flat_row_indices.reshape(src.shape), flat_column_indices.reshape(src.shape))
```

### Explanation

The idea is to find the indices that transform `dst` to its sorted version (say `s`) and find the indices that transform `s` into `src`, and then compose those indices.

First, note that the shape of `src` and `dst` don't really matter, so I will first flatten both arrays with [`np.ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html).

The first one is simple:

```
dst_to_s = np.ravel(dst).argsort()  # Now `np.ravel(dst)[dst_to_s]` equals `s`
```

For the second, we can use a little trick:

```
s_to_src = np.ravel(src).argsort().argsort()  # Now `s[s_to_src]` equals `np.ravel(src)`
```

Combining them gives us a flattened version of what you're looking for:

```
dst_to_src = dst_to_s[s_to_src]  # Now `np.ravel(dst)[dst_to_src]` equals `np.ravel(src)`
```

Now it's only a matter of reshaping this answer:

```
flat_row_indices, flat_column_indices = np.unravel_index(dst_to_src, src.shape)
indices = (flat_row_indices.reshape(src.shape), flat_column_indices.reshape(src.shape))
```

Try it out:

```
np.all(dst[indices] == src)  # Returns `True`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have to say, not being super comfortable with numpy, I had a bit of a hard time following it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the position of every element in `dst` in the `src` indices space you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

src = np.array([[8, 1],
                [2, 4]])

dst = np.array([[1, 4],
                [8, 2]])
in = np.array([np.where(x==src)[:] for x in np.nditer(dst)]).squeeze()
```

and `in` is:

```
[[0 1]
 [1 1]
 [0 0]
 [1 0]]
```

Where the first row means that `1` should be in row number 0 and column number 1 etc.

Comment: This is going to be very slow and may do unexpected things to duplicates.

Comment: @MadPhysicist regarding the duplicates I agree, but I wasn't worry since the asker said that he expect no such issue. regarding performance you are right, as the arrays get larger it won't be that efficient. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

My mind was getting completely overflowed while trying these argsorts and their inverses but then I realized that introducing some notations of [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) might help here.

The underlying part of this problem would be this sub-problem:

> Let `p` be a permutation array such that `x[p] = y`.
> Let `q` be a permutation array such that `y[q] = z`. What is a permutation `r` such that `x[r] = z`?

And the answer is `np.arange(len(x))[p][q]`. Now apply this conclusion for case `x=src`, `y=sorted(x)`, `z=dst`:

```
def find_permutation(src, dst):
    p = np.argsort(src)
    _, q = np.unique(dst, return_inverse=True)
    return np.arange(len(src))[p][q]
```

So it gives, for instance:

```
>>> find_permutation([1, 4, 8, 2], [8, 1, 2, 4])
[2 0 3 1]
```

A solution would be to find a backward permutation of flattened arrays and then reshape them back into initial structure:

```
src = np.array([[8, 1], [2, 4]])
dst = np.array([[1, 4], [8, 2]])
p = find_permutation(dst.flatten(), src.flatten())
x,y = src.shape
idx1, idx2 = np.divmod(p, y)
output = idx1.reshape(x,y), idx2.reshape(x,y)
```

**Output:**

```
(array([[1, 0], [1, 0]], dtype=int32), 
array([[0, 0], [1, 1]], dtype=int32))
```